# Setting a socket timeout in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, pear

I'm writing a script in PHP that uses PEAR's [Net_Socket](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-socket.php). I want to query servers to see if they have any current information. I send in a command and then use $socket->readLine() to get the response. However, if there is not a response, my script just waits forever. Is there anyway to either tell the socket to close after a specific amount of time or to wrap the whole function in a timeout, that if it hasn't returned by the timeout, it halts its execution?

Answer (score 0):

On the same page you linked is a link to setTimeout(): https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-socket.settimeout.php

Trying calling $socket->setTimeout( $seconds, $milliseconds ); just before calling readLine()

Comment: I believe that is for the time it waits to establish a connection. It did nothing to help me with this problem.

Comment: Having read the source for the readLine method, it does seem that setting a timeout value should have an effect. Perhaps you need to experiment more with its value?